# timsort algorithm, is galloping supplement or alternative for the binary search in merge

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort, timsort

I'm trying to understand the timsort algorithm. Wikipedia says the merge uses *almost in-place* strategy, where the runs are limited with binary search before merge sort to optimize the performance.

> Timsort performs an almost in-place merge sort, as actual in-place merge sort implementations have a high overhead. First Timsort performs a binary search to find the location in the first run of the first element in the second run, and the location in the second run of the last element in the first run. Elements before and after these locations are already in their correct place, and may be removed from further consideration.

Then, about galloping mode, the following is stated

> The individual merging above keeps a count of consecutive elements selected from the same input set. The algorithm switches to galloping mode when this reaches the minimum galloping threshold (min_gallop). This tries to capitalise on sub-runs in the data; as such, the success or failure of galloping is used to adjust the minimum galloping threshold, as an indication of whether the data does or does not contain sufficient sub-runs. (The initial threshold is MIN_GALLOP.)[6]

The *selected input set* makes me think of run resulting after the binary search optimization. But it also says

> Also, in cases where galloping is found to be less efficient than binary search, galloping mode is exited.

Which gives me contrary impression of galloping being alternative to binary search optimization.

So, is the galloping supplement or alternative to binary search optimization used for the merge? Could someone give me more clear explanation of the whole algorithm (and especially the merge and the galloping mode), as I'm relatively new in the field of algorithms in genral.